# Swapping a row and column values of list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D list swap first row, first column value with the last row, last column value, and so on...

```
list1=[[1],
       [2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9,10]]
```

After swapping it should be printed like

```
list1=[[7],
       [4,8],
       [2,5,9],
       [1,3,6,10]]
```

Is there any easy way to do this in python?

Comment: I don't see there is an easy way without loops (if you want that or define what is "easy" for you), probably you might have to resort to what you already have (it would be helpful if you added that to question as well).

Comment: thanks for the clarification and I'm just looking for whether we have any built-in function for this or not.